# Checking nodes with null data

Tags: c, binary-tree

How do I check if a node has a value? Because if I do this:

```
if(strcmp(current->left->value,"")!=0)
```

It always has a random values with hearts, smiles and other stuff even before I do this:

```
current->left = (struct baseLL*) malloc(sizeof(struct baseLL));
```

This is my struct:

```
struct baseLL {
    char value[32];
    struct baseLL *right,*left,*prev;
}; struct baseLL *current;
```

Comment: Do not cast `malloc`. But you can check its return value. If `malloc` returns `NULL` it has failed. Like this: `if (current->left = malloc(sizeof(struct baseLL)) == NULL) { // Error handling }`. How do you set `value`?

Comment: After you allocate memory for your structure, you should probably assign `right` and `left` `NULL` (and assign a good `prev` value). This way you know if there is no `left` or `right` data.

Comment: `malloc()` is like picking up a sheet of paper from the scrap pile, there may already be random garbage on it.  (`calloc()` on the other hand gives you clean sheets of paper).

Comment: calloc() is the one i'm looking for perfect for my code. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: `baseLL` keeps reminding me of "baseball".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a node has been initialized, code cannot check if the node has a value.

Good coding will initialize data upon or soon after creation.

```
int a = 1;
int b;
b = 2;
```

With allocated memory, similar initialization should promptly occur.

```
// current->left = (struct baseLL*) malloc(sizeof(struct baseLL));
current->left = malloc(sizeof(struct baseLL));  // No need for the cast

if (current->left == NULL) exit(1);  // Somehow handle OOM

// prompt initialization example
current->left->value[0] = '\0';
current->left->right = current->left->left = current->left->prev = NULL;

...
// Later on code can do the "check if the node has a value".
if( strcmp(current->left->value,"")!=0)
```

---

Notes

Recommend the following `malloc()` style
   `current->left = malloc(sizeof current->left);`

Could use `calloc()` to allocate and initialize all bits to 0 in one step. @John Hascall
   `current->left = calloc(1 /* number of elements */, sizeof current->left);`

Answer (score 3):

When you malloc a new node, the data in value are uninitialized. Therefore, the array holds garbage data that is most probably not equal to `""` (the empty string).

Instead, you can try initializing the value with `current->left->value[0]='\0';` directly after the malloc. Then, you can indeed check whether the node has a value or not with strcmp.

Comment: This indeed worked although I did strcpy(current->left->value,"") cause current->left->value[0]='\0'; did not worked